# Need PS/2 adapter in case of USB driver conflict

Tags: ps2

I had an issue when installing Windows 7, when it came time to install the USB 3.0 driver that came with the motherboard. Next thing I know when I reboot, both mouse and keyboard are no longer working and I'm forced to reinstall Windows 7 all over again, and this happened last year as well.

This time, I'm avoiding the USB 3.0 driver altogether, and it seems to work well without it even though there is a yellow triangle on the USB controller win Device Manager.

My mouse and keyboard are Logitech (keyboard is a K120) but it seems that PS/2 adapters don't work with them. What are my options?

Comment: u can troubleshoot with other mouse keyboards and ps2 adaptors, particularly different models

Comment: Note that simple (passive) USB-to-PS/2 "adapters" just route wires, it's you keyboard (or mouse, but I've never seen a mouse with adapter) that needs to understand both protocols (it switches internally according to which protocol it detects). That's why the adapters often only work with the particular keyboard they came with. So you either need a more expensive, "active" USB-to-PS/2 adapter in the right direction (USB keyboard to PS/2 host), or you need to by a keyboard that works with both protocols.

Comment: Will something like this do? Unfortunately, the genders are reversed: [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Active-USB-to-PS2-Adapter/dp/B008J56RVY/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_107_tr_img_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=EXYNM9YHA4VNFWAXVXRY)

Comment: Never mind, I've just ordered a proper PS/2 keyboard from Ebay.